# "dfx deploy index" An error occurred while running this command

Tags: debugging, desktop, motoko

I am now running the Hello, CanDB project. URL : https://ykgs2-ziaaa-aaaak-qcfya-cai.icp0.io/docs/tutorial-basics/hello-candb

I'm using mops here, not vessel, as motoko's package manager. Installation of mops was carried out according to the following url. https://mops.one/docs/install

However, the "dfx start --clean" command runs perfectly, but a bug appears when the "dfx deploy index" command is executed.

Screenshot:

[image: Bug_Screenshot]

"dfx deploy index", when I run this command, this error appeared.

```
root@v995146575:~/Renovaee_beta# dfx deploy index
Deploying: index
Creating a wallet canister on the local network.
The wallet canister on the "local" network for user "default" is "bnz7o-iuaaa-aaaaa-qaaaa-cai"
Creating canisters...
Creating canister index...
index canister created with canister id: bkyz2-fmaaa-aaaaa-qaaaq-cai
Building canisters...
Error: Failed while trying to deploy canisters.
Caused by: Failed while trying to deploy canisters.
  Failed to build all canisters.
    Failed while trying to build all canisters.
      The build step failed for canister 'bkyz2-fmaaa-aaaaa-qaaaq-cai' (index) with an embedded error: Failed to build Motoko canister 'index'.: Failed to compile Motoko.: Failed to run 'moc'.: The command '"/root/.cache/dfinity/versions/0.14.3/moc" "/root/Renovaee_beta/src/index/IndexCanister.mo" "-o" "/root/Renovaee_beta/.dfx/local/canisters/index/index.wasm" "-c" "--debug" "--idl" "--stable-types" "--public-metadata" "candid:service" "--public-metadata" "candid:args" "--actor-idl" "/root/Renovaee_beta/.dfx/local/canisters/idl/" "--actor-alias" "index" "bkyz2-fmaaa-aaaaa-qaaaq-cai" "--package" "base" ".mops/base@0.9.8/src" "--package" "candb" ".mops/candb@1.0.1/src" "--package" "stable-hash-map" ".mops/_github/stable-hash-map@v0.2.1/src" "--package" "btree" ".mops/_github/btree@v0.3.2/src" "--package" "matchers" ".mops/_github/matchers@v1.3.0/src" "--package" "array" ".mops/_github/array@v0.2.0/src" "--package" "encoding" ".mops/_github/encoding@v0.3.2/src" "--package" "stable-rbtree" ".mops/_github/stable-rbtree@v0.6.1/src" "--package" "stablebuffer" ".mops/_github/stablebuffer@v0.2.0/src" "--package" "map" ".mops/_github/map@v7.0.0/src" "--package" "candy" ".mops/_github/candy@0.2.0/src" "--package" "motoko-base" ".mops/_github/motoko-base@moc-0.9.1/src" "--package" "shared" "shared" "--incremental-gc"' failed with exit status 'exit status: 1'.
Stdout:

Stderr:
(unknown location): package error [M0012], file "shared" (for package `shared`) does not exist
```

Comment: Have you looked at the thing that is producing a non-zero exit code? Does that thing have a `--verbose` flag that you could use to get a useful error message?